# Outlook export a rule which sends to sent folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, mail-rule

I have a rule which sends an item to my sent folder. Is there a way to export this rule so that when somebody else imports it the item would go to their sent folder? not my sent folder

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not configure the same rule in another user's Outlook directly? That's the easiest way.

If you insist on exporting rules from the Outlook client, please try the following:

- Click File
- Manage Rules & Alerts
- Click options
- Export Rules.

[image]